# mlstate/opa vagrant box installation issue

Tags: windows-7, vagrant, 32-bit, opa

I stumble upon the [OPA framework for Javascript](http://opalang.org) and decided to give it a shot.

Prefering a Vagrant Box, I did as suggested:

```
vagrant init mlstate/opa
vagrant up
```

but unfortunately it failed: Allegedly the box file is corrupted as `bsdtar.exe` couldn't even recognize the format while unpacking it.

What can I do, I need an official OPA Vagrant Box up and running on my Win7 machine to harness it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on my Mac laptop. Installing the Vagrant Box from Vagrant Cloud does not seem to be working...

In alternative, you can try downloading the box file using the torrent on this link : http://opalang.org/Opa%20vagrant%20box.torrent

Once the box file is downloaded, issue the following commands :

```
vagrant box add opa-box file:///your_path_to_downloaded_file/opa.box
vagrant init opa-box
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

This works on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the link leads to a redirect page to Google Drive. Bsdtar cannot open the archive because it's an HTML file. You can download it and add it using imikael21's instructions.

Here's the link it leads to: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B1UEOBxsn2GiN3ZpbFdMek1FNjQ

The attempted link: https://vagrantcloud.com/mlstate/opa/version/1/provider/virtualbox.box